# How to rewrite url to match root directory?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have this url: http://example.com/resources/app/app.css

And the file is here in my filesystem: /home/neuquino/www/app/app.css

So, I want to have something like this:

```
location /resources(.*) {
  root /home/neuquino/www;
}
```

How can I make this rewrite to work on Nginx?

**NOTE:** creating /home/neuquino/www/resources directory is not an option for me.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented in the question, the solution was to use the **[alias](http://nginx.org/r/alias)** instruction.

```
location /resources/ {
  alias /home/neuquino/www/;
}
```